# Смена URL в адресной строке

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

Есть обычная фильтрация в интернет магазине на ajax.
Переменные формируются примерно так:

l_elem_sort="&sort="+sort

Далее в success меняю URL страницы

```
var stateParameters={};
history.pushState(stateParameters,"New page title",cat_url+"?"+l_elem_manuf+l_elem_sort
+l_elem_direction+l_elem_limit+l_elem_page_param)
```

УРЛ реально меняется как надо, т.е становится например

site.ru/detskie_velosipedy.html?&filter_id=103&sort=price&direction=asc&on_page=20&page=1

Далее перехожу на страницу товара - > в браузере нажимаю "назад" и у меня урл

site.ru/detskie_velosipedy.html?sort=price`&amp;`direction=asc`&amp;`filter_id=103`&amp;`on_page=20

т.е **&** заменились на **`&amp;`**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где и что Я не учел. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте получить амперсанд обратно:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf('&amp;') != -1) {
    var url = document.URL;
    var url = url.split('&amp;').join('&');
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Unexpected token .

Comment: Извиняюсь, обновил ответ

Comment: работает.  А как то можно, не запихивая, в $(document).ready(function() { }); выполнить раньше. а то ждать 2 раза пока страница загрузится.

Comment: А вы и не запихивайте. Это ведь джаваскрипт, он работает без `$(document).ready`

Comment: и вправду. тупанул. Большее спасибо!